# How to add the int elements of 2 lists python

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

So I am relatively new to Python. I have this code:

```
vel = [4, 3]

list = [[4, 5]
        [6, 4]
        [7, 5]
        [3, 4]
       ]
```

The numbers are random within a range, but are always ints.
I want to add the `vel` list to each of the sub-lists of list so that I have this result:

```
list = [[8, 8]
        [10, 7]
        [11, 8]
        [6, 8]
       ]
```

Please show me a *'pythonic'* way of doing this.

EDIT: I have read other threads about adding the elements of a 1D list, but I can't seem to get it to work with the 2-D list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you want to mutate the original list.

```
vel = [4, 3]
lst = [[4, 5]  # changed this identifier. Don't shadow Python built-ins
       [6, 4]
       [7, 5]
       [3, 4]]

lst = [[vel[0]+sublst[0], vel[1]+sublst[1]] for sublst in lst]
```

Comment: I wouldn't call it `list`, even though that was the name given in the question.

Comment: I am a bit confused, where is sublst initiated?

Comment: @Mechanic `... for sublst in lst`. This is a list comprehension. They're probably the best part of Python :D

Answer (score 2):

```
vel = [4, 3]
L = [[4, 5],
     [6, 4],
     [7, 5],
     [3, 4]]
answer = [[sum(s) for s in zip(vel, sub)] for sub in L]
```

PS: It's a terrible idea to name your variables after data types (`file`, `list`, `tuple`, `bool`, `int`, etc)